# Date literals returning nothing in Apex Test

Tags: soql, unit-test, failing-tests, schedulebatch, date-literals

I'm doing the following in a test class. First inserting one record and then doing a record count to see that there is still only the one record in the DB. However when the query runs I get 0 records found. The odd part is that same query is working in the batch.

```
application__c app = new application__c(Business_Name__c='test', Date_Received__c=Date.today(), Status__c ='Analysis', Date_for_Email__c=Date.today().addDays(-2));
insert app;

Integer recordCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM application__c WHERE Date_for_Email__c = N_DAYS_AGO:2 and (Status__c = 'Analysis' OR Status__c = 'Analysis - Error Found')];
```

This is just a basic test class for now

```
        integer numberOfAccounts = 1;
    integer mailListSize = 0;
    application__c app = new application__c(Business_Name__c='test', Date_Received__c=Date.today(), Status__c ='Analysis', Date_for_Email__c=Date.today().addDays(-2), Primary_Contact_Email__c='jsunga@mtb.com');
    List<application__c> applications = new List<application__c>();
    insert app;
    applications.add(app);

    Test.startTest();

    EmailHandler obj = new EmailHandler();
    mailListSize = obj.send2DayEmail(applications);
    Test.stopTest();


    Integer actualNumberOfAccounts = [SELECT COUNT() FROM application__c WHERE Date_for_Email__c= N_DAYS_AGO:2 and (Status__c = 'Analysis' OR Status__c = 'Analysis - Error Found')];
    System.assertEquals(numberOfAccounts, actualNumberOfAccounts);
    System.assertEquals(mailListSize, 1);
```

Comment: Can you share the test class code? At least the test method in question and the outer class definition (and any annotations)

Comment: just added the code. It's weird because the only thing I'm doing is inserting one record and then querying that same record with specific conditions to make sure theres still only 1 record.

Comment: so the actual batch is working (mailListSize == 1) but the query in the test method doesn't? (actualNumberOfAccounts != 1)?

Comment: Yes that is the case. When I change the query to be more generic however i.e. Date != null it picks up the count of the 1 record. I tried to include Date.today.addDays(-2) as a variable to use for the query and that seemed to not work either.

Comment: I don't suppose your batch by any chance changes the Date_for_Email__c field? Send Email then update to send again next week or anything?

Comment: It doesn't. Other than the insert no updates are done to the initial record. I can confirm the record data is the following:
USER_DEBUG [62]|DEBUG|application__c:{Business_Name__c=test, Date_Received__c=2020-04-22 00:00:00, Status__c=Analysis, Date_for_Email__c=2020-04-20 00:00:00, Primary_Contact_Email__c=test@test.com}

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you change the query outside of the batch call to N_DAYS_AGO:1 or 3, do you get the record?

Comment: I just tried N_DAYS_AGO:1 and 3 and no success. I see what you mean in regards to it possibly being offset by the time settings. This is very strange as I can use the exact query in the batch and loop through the results (there's only 1) and find the exact object that was just inserted. Running the batch itself also sends the email correctly as well...it's just in the test I can't find the record..

Comment: If you don't do Count() and just do Application__c applications = [SELECT Id FROM Application__c ....] and do .size() do you get anything? Sorry for all the questions, just wanting to know what exactly this is an issue with!

Comment: Just tested this and got the same issue. My assert failed where the expected was 1 but the actual was 0. The query doesn't seem to pick up anything when using the date literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date.today()` method returns a dateTime of today's date at 0 milliseconds.

When you say `WHERE Some_Date_Time_Field__c = :Date.today()`, you are looking for any record where there is an exact millisecond match for example:

Some_Date_Time_Field__c = 2020-04-22 00:00:00

You should change your query filter to `WHERE Some_Date_Time_Field__c = TODAY`. This will change your results to be any record where it was actually created today.

Comment: How would I filter it where the date is two days ago not including exact time.

Comment: use `WHERE Some_Date_Time_Field__c = LAST_N_DAYS:2`

Comment: That sort of works but I need it to be exactly 2 days ago and not including 1 day ago.

Comment: `WHERE (Date.toay()-2) <= Some_Date_Time_Field__c  AND Some_Date_Time_Field__c  < (Date.today()-1)`